# python and regex

Tags: python, regex

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

str = raw_input("String containing email...\t")
match = re.search(r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+', str)
 if match:
  print match.group()
```

it's not the most complicated code, and i'm looking for a way to get ALL of the matches, if it's possible.

Comment: I don't know python, but in perl the modifier to get all matches is g, so maybe r'[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+'g would work.

Comment: I'm sure you're already aware of this, but just in case: that regular expression misses some valid email addresses and will find some invalid addresses.

Comment: @tekknolagi: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses

Comment: @tekknolagi: Depends on your requirements.

Comment: was just experimenting with regex, that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
    Return a list of all non-overlapping matches in the string.

    If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a
    list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
    has more than one group.

    Empty matches are included in the result.
```

As far as the actual regular expression for identifying email addresses goes... See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/78845).

Also, be careful using `str` as a variable name. This will hide the [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=str#str) built-in.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try for find() or findall()

> findall() matches all occurrences of a
>   pattern, not just the first one as
>   search() does. For example, if one was
>   a writer and wanted to find all of the
>   adverbs in some text, he or she might
>   use findall()

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs

Answer (score 0):

- You don't use raw_input in the way you used. Just use raw_input to get the input from the console.
- Don't override built-in's such as str. Use a meaningful name and assign it a whole string value.
- Also it is a good idea many a times to compile your pattern have it a Regex object to match the string against. (illustrated in the code)

I just realized that a complete regex to match an email id exactly as per RFC822 [could be a pageful](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) otherwise this snippet should be useful.

```
import re

inputstr = "something@exmaple.com, 121@airtelnet.com, ra@g.net, etc etc\t"
mailsrch = re.compile(r'[\w\-][\w\-\.]+@[\w\-][\w\-\.]+[a-zA-Z]{1,4}')
matches = mailsrch.findall(inputstr)
print matches
```